# vbscript/sql adding a column to an insert statement

Tags: sql, vbscript, insert-query

I am trying to add an additional column and value to an existing insert query - both integers, and running into trouble.

Anything to look out for?

Comment: Anything to show for us?

Answer (score 1):

you don't give much to go in in your question:

> I am trying to add an additional
>   column and value to an existing insert
>   query - both integers, and running
>   into trouble.
>
> Anything to look out for?

it is best practice to list all columns you intend to include values for in the list of columns, so make sure you add them there, as well as the VALUES list:

```
insert into YourTable (col1, col2,..., newCol1, newCol2) 
VALUES (1,2,...,new1, new2)
```

make sure the you get the column names spelled correct and that the table actually has those new columns in it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the column name sequence is the same as your insert data sequence.
Example

INSERT INTO TABLENAME 
(ColumnName1,ColumnName2) VALUES (1,'data')

Becomes

INSERT INTO TABLENAME 
(ColumnName1,ColumnName2,**ColumnNameNEW**) VALUES (1,'data','**newcolumndata**')

Notice both the new column name and the new data are in the third position in the sequence.